# Update two or more models at same time with UpdateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Is there some way to update two or more models at the same time with UpdateView? For example having this:

```
class PEEncargadoView(UpdateModelMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Encargado
    form_class = FormEncargado
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'productores/PE/encargado.html'
```

Update other models besides of Encargado but in this same view

I know that this could be possible overriding get_context_data, but exactly how? if I don't need to pass any variables to the template.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it with UpdateModelMixin - it's designed for working with a single model.

This question shows how to work with multiple forms in CBV: [Django: Can class-based views accept two forms at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497693/django-can-class-based-views-accept-two-forms-at-a-time).

Django has formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/ which can be used together with ModelForm to allow edition of multiple models on one page.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont need to render two forms in one template. Exactly Im looking for a solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282885/update-in-three-models-at-the-same-time-in-form-valid-django?noredirect=1#comment48668678_30282885